# Node / Mongo - Increment and get a counter value for multiple clients

Tags: node.js, mongodb, counter, atomic

I am using NodeJs and MongoDB.

I have a scenario where multiple clients store orders into the DB and i would like to give every order a incrementing daily order number, which turns to zero after it reached 999.

I am not sure what strategy should i choose to be guarantee every order gets the next number even if more than one client try to get the next number simultaneously.

I was thinking of making a collection with one document which holds than number, and than applying some kind of lock while a single client updates that document. But i am not sure if it is the right way of doing it.

Comment: Some useful information at: [Generating Globally Unique Identifies to use with MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/generating-globally-unique-identifiers-for-use-with-mongodb).

Comment: A GUID would not be very helpful, i would prefer a human readable integer number